# How to group consecutive elements values based on the key value in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, grouping

I'm a Python beginner and need help on this.

My input is

```
input: [(5, 1), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3), (6, 3)]
```

input contains `[(value,key)]`

My output should be

```
0,1,2

3,4,6

5
```

The consecutive values need be grouped based on the key count and then sorted to show the final output.

ie) 5 appears once and should be grouped alone

0, 1, 2 has the key count as 3 and hence should be grouped together

3, 4, 6 has the key count as 3 and hence should be grouped together

The final output should be in sorted order and look like this

```
0,1,2

3,4,6

5
```

I tried with `itertools.groupby()` and it only groups the values based on similar keys.

Any solutions would be helpful.

I tried the following:

```
sortedValidGroups = sorted(validGroups,key = lambda x:x[1])

print(sortedValidGroups)

groups = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(sortedValidGroups, itemgetter(1))]

print(groups)
```

output:

```
[[(5, 1)], [(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3), (6, 3)]]
```

But my output should be (This is of the form`[(values,keys)]`)

```
[[(5, 1)],[(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3)],[(3, 3), (4, 3), (6, 3)]]
```

and then I need to sort the values to produce the final output

```
0,1,2

3,4,6

5
```

Comment: "I tried with grouby itertools and it only groups the values based on similar keys." Okay, so a) show the code you actually tried; b) explain what is the difficulty in getting from here to the solution. Did you read the documentation? Are you unable to produce the lists of values for each key? Are you unable to sort those lists? Or just what exactly?

Comment: sortedValidGroups = sorted(validGroups,key = lambda x:x[1])
    print(sortedValidGroups)
    groups = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(sortedValidGroups, itemgetter(1))]
    print(groups)
    
    output:
    [[(5, 1)], [(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3), (6, 3)]]
    
    But my output should be (This is of the form[(values,keys)])
    [[(5, 1)],[(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3)],[(3, 3), (4, 3), (6, 3)]]
    
    and then I need to sort the values to produce the final output
    
    0,1,2
    
    3,4,6
    
    5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your solution looks good, just need a nice ending...
taking from your final output, to partition the array you can do the following

```
a = [[(5, 1)], [(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3), (6, 3)]]
b = [[(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2)]]

def regroup(lst):
  tmp = list()
  for i in range(len(lst)):
    step = lst[i][0][1]
    for j in range(0,len(lst[i]),step):
      tmp.append(lst[i][j:j+step])

  return sorted(tmp , key=lambda x : x[0][0])


regroup(a)
[[(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3)], [(3, 3), (4, 3), (6, 3)], [(5, 1)]]

regroup(b)
[[(0, 2), (1, 2)], [(2, 2), (3, 2)]]
```

Comment: `xrange`? OP was asking about Python 3

Comment: Since I need it for python3, I just changed xrange to range.Thank you, Shafaq. That worked. Thanks Georgy & Karl

Comment: Sorry, the solution didn't work for the following input: :[[(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)], [(3, 2)]]    The expected output for the above input is [[(0, 2), (1, 2)], [(2, 2), (3, 2)]]

Comment: than I didn't understand the algorithm... what suppose to be the group size? depends on the value (key,value)?

Comment: @shahaf The count/group size can be anything: 1 to n; [(0, 2), (1, 2)] The group size here is determined by the second element 2, Hence consecutive elements need 0,1 need to be grouped since 2 is the 2nd element and should be restricted to 2 elements.

Comment: @ReeceAPoole so why did you say the solution is not working if the group size can be anything? can you explain what is the criteria to make the split by?

Comment: @shahaf - the group size is determined by the value. This value can be anything from 1 to n..for eg: consider my input as [[(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)], [(3, 2)]] the output should be :  [[(0, 2), (1, 2)], [(2, 2), (3, 2)]]

Comment: @ReeceAPoole - fixed the code according to your specifications

Comment: @Shahaf - Thank you. It worked perfectly for all the scenarios.